# How to name a thread in Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading

I have a multithreaded Linux application written in C/C++.  I have [chosen names for my threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149932/naming-conventions-for-threads).  To aid debugging, I would like these names to be visible in GDB, "top", etc.  Is this possible, and if so how?

(There are plenty of [reasons to know the thread name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763041/thread-names-when-do-you-need-to-know-them).  Right now I want to know which thread is taking up 50% CPU (as reported by 'top').  And when debugging I often need to switch to a different thread - currently I have to do "`thread apply all bt`" then look through pages of backtrace output to find the right thread).

The [Windows solution is here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100322223513/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs(VS.80).aspx); what's the Linux one?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026531/thread-name-longer-than-15-chars

Comment: Somehow the `prctl()` (and `pthread_setname_np()` did not work for me. It changed the name of ALL my threads. So rather useless. Instead I had to write the name to the comm file. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68676407/how-do-i-change-the-name-of-one-single-thread-in-linux/68687132#68687132

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Posix Threads?

This evidently won't compile, but it will give you an idea of where to go hunting. I'm not even sure its the right `PR_` command, but i think it is. It's been a while...

```
  #include <sys/prctl.h>
  prctl(PR_SET_NAME,"<null> terminated string",0,0,0)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!  The documentation says PR_SET_NAME sets the process name; but that documentation is wrong - it does actually set the thread name.  Now "top" and "ps -L" show the thread name.

Comment: Glad it worked, I wasnt sure if it was even the right Constant for it,   :)

Comment: I've always identified threads based on the start function as shown in the thread's stack-trace. Nice to know there's a clean alternative.

Comment: Further investigation shows that busybox's "top" and "ps" don't report thread names.  You need the full versions from the "procps" package.

Comment: you can force "ps" to show that name with the c switch (ps Hcx for example).

Comment: @arsane not the busybox's one. Busybox tools are very limited, sometimes have a different args. And e.g. its `free` just give wrong results.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using a library like [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) the [Thread](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/5.6.9/html/ace/a00565.html) has a way to specify the thread name when creating a new thread.

BSD Unix has also a [pthread_set_name_np](http://www.rootr.net/man/man/pthread_set_name_np/3) call.

Otherwise you can use [prctl](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/prctl.2.html) as mentioned by Fusspawn.

Comment: On Linux it's called `pthread_setname_np` and it was added in glibc 2.11.2.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369738/can-i-set-the-name-of-a-thread-in-pthreads-linux) is, probably, the most-detailed answer on the subject.