# pgrep does not search for long (more than 15 chars) process name

Tags: linux, procps

My process name is `core-plugin-loader`

```
core-plugin-loader --file=/usr/lib/blah.so &

pi@kyb-pi4 /usr> pgrep core-plugin-loader
pi@kyb-pi4 /usr> pgrep core-plugin-loa
13892
pi@kyb-pi4 /usr> pgrep -a core-plugin-loa
13892 core-plugin-loader --file=/usr/lib/blah.so
pi@kyb-pi4 /usr> pgrep -a core-plugin-loader
```

Version:

```
pgrep from procps-ng 3.3.15

> head -1 /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
```

Looks very strange. How to fix this for `pgrep`?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026531/thread-name-longer-than-15-chars) is Q about thread name. But I ask for a process name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be in `man pgrep` :

> NOTES
>
> The process name used for matching is limited to the 15 characters
>   present in  the  output of  /proc/pid/stat.   Use  the  -f  option  to
>   match  against  the complete command line,
>          /proc/pid/cmdline.