# Change process name without changing argv[0] in Linux

Tags: c, linux, process, rename, argv

I need to modify the process name of my program in C language.
I precise, this is not the name of a thread that I want to change.
I want to change the name of my program, but the only solution I found, is to modify the value of `argv[0]`.
I also found another solution with `prctl(PR_SET_NAME, "newname")`, but this solution doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to name a thread in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778085/how-to-name-a-thread-in-linux)

Comment: _"The documentation says PR_SET_NAME sets the process name; but that documentation is wrong - it does actually set the thread name. Now "top" and "ps -L" show the thread name."_ -- [user9876 Apr 22 '09 at 17:39](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778085/how-to-name-a-thread-in-linux#comment588964_778124)

Comment: PR_SET_NAME flag is supported since Linux 2.6.9

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The differences between invoking `prctl` and modify `argv[0]` are:

- modify `argv[0]` changes information in `/proc/$pid/cmdline`
- invoking `prctl(PR_SET_NAME)` changes information in `/proc/$pid/status`

That means you will get difference name of your process issuing `ps -a` and `ps -ax`.

If you expects same process name for different arguments while executing ps, you can do them both (i.e., change `argv[0]` and invoke `prctl`).

Hope the answer helps.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
char *process_name = "aaa\0";
memcpy((void *)argv[0], process_name, sizeof(process_name));
```

/*
***explain：***
The space allocated for argv[0] could be smaller than the name that you want to give and then you will be overwritting some other unrelated memory. argv[0] size could be just 2 and if your process name is "averylongprocessname" you will be overflowing argv[0]. You need to strlen(argv[0]) and use that in memcpy.
thx @ecerulm

*/

Comment: I think that the \0 is unnecessary - isn't it already silently appended to a literal string of characters?

Comment: @Chap: it's true for `strcpy`, not for `memcpy`.

Comment: Seems that you have to overwrite all characters of origin `argv[0]`, is it true? So you can't have process names bigger than original name

Comment: The space allocated for `argv[0]` could be smaller than the name that you want to give and then you will be overwritting some other unrelated memory. `argv[0]` size could be just 2 and if your process name is "averylongprocessname" you will be overflowing `argv[0]`. You need to `strlen(argv[0])` and use that in `memcpy`.

Comment: The `\0` is unnecessary. Also, `sizeof` is incorrect here as it would return the size of a pointer (typically 4 or 8 bytes). You want something more like `strncpy(argv[0], process_name, strlen(process_name)` or `memcpy(argv[0], process_name, (strlen(argv[0]) < strlen(process_name)+1) ? strlen(argv[0]) : strlen(process_name)+1)`