# how is the thread name set in log4cplus?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, log4cplus

I'm evaluating log4cplus for a multi threaded C++ application on linux. The TTCCLayout and the PatternLayout allow the thread name to be displayed. In my tests there was never a name but just a meaningless number. I'm not using the thread class of log4cplus. How does log4cplus determine this thread name and is it possible to set it myself?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/778085/841108

Comment: I guess it's not that easy. I had to dig through my thread library and successfully used prctl to set a name, but no effect. Even the test application in the log4cplus source does not show thread names. Maybe I should ask this on the log4cplus devel mailing list.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4cplus (as of version 1.1.1 or earlier) does not have any [PatternLayout](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1PatternLayout.html) formatter for thread names. It only has two thread related formatters:

- `%t` - prints thread ID; for *nix, it is whatever value `pthread_t`
  represents, usually an `int` value or a pointer value
- `%T` - prints alternative thread ID; for Linux, prints the value
  returned by `syscall (SYS_gettid)`

There is definitely some room for improvement.

Comment: You're right and that's what I was told now [on the log4cplus mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CAKw7uVhT9_xEac_svRUmtLuLqhW_yohzvRQXtQzt5rvSXC5VTw%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=log4cplus-devel) as well. However there are NDC or MDC facilities I could use. I'll have another look in the log4cplus code for that. O:-) Thanks for your help. :-)