# Is there a portable way to give thread name with Qt?

Tags: multithreading, qt, portability

I know I can set thread name (the one visible in gdb and htop) in Linux [using `prctl()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778085/how-to-name-a-thread-in-linux). But with another OSes this most likely won't work. Also, I could try [using `pthread_setname_np()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369738/can-i-set-the-name-of-a-thread-in-pthreads-linux), which is a bit more available across POSIX systems, but still lacks full compatibility.

So I'd like to have some more portable way, maybe something `QThread` provides which I've not found. Is there any such way?

Comment: You could work with compile flags, depending on the OS you are compiling for.

Comment: boost doesn't have a way so I doubt QT will

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing in the `QThread` API to manually manage the system name of the thread, however, since version 4.8.3, Qt will automatically set the name of your thread to the name of the thread object (`QObject::objectName()`).

This is handled in the implementations of `QThread` as described below.

You have something like this in [`qthread_unix.cpp`](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/b6d1a35d6cb464f643d7905ec731069e729d4ad4%3asrc/corelib/thread/qthread_unix.cpp#L283):

```
#if (defined(Q_OS_LINUX) || defined(Q_OS_MAC) || defined(Q_OS_QNX))
static void setCurrentThreadName(pthread_t threadId, const char *name)
{
#  if defined(Q_OS_LINUX) && !defined(QT_LINUXBASE)
    Q_UNUSED(threadId);
    prctl(PR_SET_NAME, (unsigned long)name, 0, 0, 0);
#  elif defined(Q_OS_MAC)
    Q_UNUSED(threadId);
    pthread_setname_np(name);
#  elif defined(Q_OS_QNX)
    pthread_setname_np(threadId, name);
#  endif
}
#endif

/* 
 * [...]
 */

QString objectName = thr->objectName();

if (Q_LIKELY(objectName.isEmpty()))
    setCurrentThreadName(thr->d_func()->thread_id, thr->metaObject()->className());
else
    setCurrentThreadName(thr->d_func()->thread_id, objectName.toLocal8Bit());
```

And the equivalent in [`qthread_win.cpp`](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/b6d1a35d6cb464f643d7905ec731069e729d4ad4%3asrc/corelib/thread/qthread_win.cpp#L278):

```
typedef struct tagTHREADNAME_INFO
{
    DWORD dwType;      // must be 0x1000
    LPCSTR szName;     // pointer to name (in user addr space)
    HANDLE dwThreadID; // thread ID (-1=caller thread)
    DWORD dwFlags;     // reserved for future use, must be zero
} THREADNAME_INFO;

void qt_set_thread_name(HANDLE threadId, LPCSTR threadName)
{
    THREADNAME_INFO info;
    info.dwType = 0x1000;
    info.szName = threadName;
    info.dwThreadID = threadId;
    info.dwFlags = 0;

    __try
    {
        RaiseException(0x406D1388, 0, sizeof(info)/sizeof(DWORD), (const ULONG_PTR*)&info);
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION)
    {
    }
}

/* 
 * [...]
 */

QByteArray objectName = thr->objectName().toLocal8Bit();
qt_set_thread_name((HANDLE)-1, objectName.isEmpty() ? thr->metaObject()->className() : objectName.constData());
```

Note that on Windows, the above code won't be executed if `QT_NO_DEBUG` is set, thus **it won't work in *Release* mode**.

Comment: This seems to only be true for new enough Qt versions. I don't see behavior cited by @Marek in 4.8.1. Instead all my threads have the name coinciding with name of binary. Also, `grep` for `setCurrentThreadName` doesn't find anything in the distro-supplied source tree. Anyway, seems this is the first real support of this in Qt, so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, as you can see [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/commit/aa21fcac3672cc6f0dca064b34bbe02ca4f4def7), that feature was implemented for debugging purpose. I'm actually surprised that it's referenced in the Qt documentation since it's not much more than a debugging workaround.

Answer (score 7):

In [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html#managing-threads) you can find:

> To choose the name that your thread will be given (as identified by
> the command ps -L on Linux, for example), you can **call setObjectName()
> before starting the thread**. If you don't call setObjectName(), the
> name given to your thread will be the **class name** of the runtime type
> of your thread object (for example, "RenderThread" in the case of the
> Mandelbrot Example, as that is the name of the QThread subclass). Note
> that this is currently not available with release builds on Windows.